# Type-safe Equals()

Tags: c#, equals, type-safety

As my (unit-)test coverage is still quite low, unfortunately, I have to find lots of errors the hard way. Therefore, during refactoring, I heavily rely on type checking of the C# compiler.

Today, I fixed a bug introduced during refactoring by missing a line with `x.Equals(aThingWrappingOriginalThing)`. As it's `bool Equals(object T)`, the compiler did not complain. However, 90% of the time I use `Equals()` directly (instead through the BCL), I intend to logically compare objects of the same type.

Now I'm wondering why I've never seen someone promoting a type-safe version of `Equals()` for such situations (in C#). Is there a best practice for this?

I'm tempted to use an extension method for those comparisions, like so:

```
public static bool SafeEquals<T>(this T a, T b)
{
    if (a == null) return b == null;
    return a.Equals(b);
}
public static bool SafeEquals<X>(this IEquatable<X> a, IEquatable<X> b)
{
    if (a == null) return b == null;
    return a.Equals(b);
}
```

Could these be optimized?

Here's the only blog post about the topic I found, for java:
http://rickyclarkson.blogspot.com/2006/12/making-equalsobject-type-safe.html

Comment: Here is some background on the topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for

```
EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x,y);
```

this supports `IEquatable<T>` (if implemented), else uses the potentially-boxing `Equals(object)`; it supports classes and structs, with expected null-behaviour for both, including support for `Nullable<T>` (without boxing).

Comment: Thanks, sounds great. Does it hurt performance to wrap it into an extension method? Will it be inlined?

Comment: @Equalizer extension methods are static-call, so: not really, no. It is unlikely to be inclined because .Default is an instance of any of a number of concrete implementations, depending on the strategy to be used. The decision/reflction is only done once per T, so it is cached - but not inlined.

Answer (score 2):

What I see looks good to me.

My 2 cents: I think it would be simpler to skip the null checks, and use this:

```
public static bool SafeEquals<T>(this T a, T b)
{
    return object.Equals(a, b);
}
```

There are very few cases in which that would deviate from intended behaviour. One of them is when `Equals` returns false when both objects are the same object (which should never happen anyway).

For reference, here is the decompiled `object.Equals`, so you can see for yourself what happens.

```
public static bool Equals(object objA, object objB)
{
    return ((objA == objB) || (((objA != null) && (objB != null)) && objA.Equals(objB)));
}
```

Comment: `Object.Equals` checks if they both point to the same data on the heap, not if they are the same.

Comment: @Kendall the first implementation here is just a wrapper around object.Equals, for that, why not just let the consumer call object.Equals for all that it's worth

Comment: @ColeJohnson Maybe by default. But there is a difference between `Equals` and `ReferenceEquals`

Comment: @KendallFrey because I misread it ;p Ignore me on that. HOWEVER! there is still a glitch; it will cause boxing for some structs. Not sure whether that matters.